# postfix smtpd_restrictions not working

Tags: postfix

I am trying to setup `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to allow only specific users to send mail to the group mail id. But postfix does not seem to restrict . I am using postfix 3.5.6 installed on debian 10. Below is my `main.cf`. Can anyone help to resolve the issue.

```
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)

biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.crt

smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.key

smtpd_use_tls=yes

smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions =

myhostname = mail.example.com

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

myorigin = /etc/mailname

mydestination = localhost, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com

relayhost =

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

mailbox_size_limit = 0

recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all

inet_protocols = ipv4

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,  permit_mynetworks, 
reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access,hash:/etc/postfix/protected, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_una$

smtpd_restriction_classes = natsys

natsys = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/natsys, reject

virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, 

mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, mysql:/$

virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, 

mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps$

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

smtp_tls_security_level = may

smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

smtpd_tls_lsmtpd_tls_received_header = yes

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot

smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

#smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 

smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

message_size_limit = 52428800oglevel = 1
```

I created protected email iD in the `/etc/postfix/protected` file and created natsys file with users who are allowed to send email to the group id and also ran postmap/restart postfix service.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks
Rishi

Comment: Did you run postmap on the  /etc/postfix/protected file? You do that to create a hashed version.

Comment: Yes i did run for both protected and natsys files